# Drupal Views & Exposed Filter Dropdowns

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-views

I'm using Profile to add a "Department" field to user profiles.
I'm using Views to create a view of users, with "Department" being an Exposed Filter.
The Exposed Filter is a textfield. I'd like for it to be a select dropdown that is populated with all possible values.

Is anyone aware of a module that will alter Views filters, changing fields from textfields to select dropdowns?

Drupal 6. Views 2. The profile field is a single-line textfield (with autocomplete).

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue in a project
fields that are textboxes show be select box.
as  attachment image shows in '**FILTER CRITERIA**' choose your field
in '**Filter type to expose**' part choose '**Grouped filters**'
a table will be shown that you manually can add your data as options

this solution is good when you know your options

this is my RTL settings for expose a textbox filter
[image: this is my RTL settings for expose a textbox filter]

this is my RTL settings for expose a textbox options
[image: this is my RTL settings for expose a textbox options]

and in UI - client side this field will be shown like this
[image: and in UI - client side this field will be shown like this]

Answer (score 0):

What kind of profile field is "Department"? I'm assuming it's one of single-line textfield, multi-line textfield, checkbox or list selection. I only tested it with a list selection, but if you check "Force single" then the exposed filter will be a select dropdown.

Assuming you mean Drupal 6. The above is true with Views 2.x and 3.x on D6.

Comment: It's a single-line textfield (with autocomplete), so "Force single" isn't an option. D6, Views 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify an existing filter, follow the accepted solution [provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032843/drupal-views-custom-modded-sql).

If altering an existing filter does not satisfy your requirements, then [this step-by-step tutorial](http://www.chadcf.com/blog/creating-custom-filters-drupal-and-views) will help you creating your own custom Views filter.