# Drupal Views - Custom / Modded SQL

Tags: sql, drupal, view, profile, checkbox

I am having an issue with the "Profile Checkboxes" module which stores custom profile fields comma separated.

The issue is if I create a view to filter by a value. The SQL result ends up being something like this:

```
...AND (profile_values_profile_interests.value in ('Business and Investment'))...
```

Which will not return any data since the value is stored like this:

"Business and Investment, Case Law, Labor Law, Tax Law"

I just need to adjust the SQL so that it is making sure the field contains the selected value

Is there anything I can do to adjust this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a 'quick hack' solution, you could try implementing [`hook_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7.x-3.x) in a custom module, check $view->name (and eventually also $view->current_display) to ensure you are dealing with the right view/display, and then manipulate $query as needed.

---

**EDIT:** Looks like the underlying problem has been addressed by the module maintainer in the meantime - [see John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032843/drupal-views-custom-modded-sql/5035646#5035646) ...

Comment: Great! I never created a module before but this worked out perfect. Thanks!

Comment: One issue I am running into is the conversion of ('%s'), if I use LIKE %%s% in my query it doesn't convert. How would I do that?

Comment: @kilrizzy: You need to [escape every '%' that should not be replaced by adding another one in front of it](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.pgsql.inc/function/db_query/6#comment-5114), so with your example, `LIKE %%%s%%` should do the trick.

Comment: Awesome thank you! I was trying to escape it with \, that works great

Comment: Although this does work, the downside is that every single view in the site will go thru the alter hook.

Answer (score 4):

I'm the creator and maintainer of [Profile Checkboxes](http://drupal.org/project/profile_checkboxes) and thought you might be interested to know that the new version of the module now stores the values as serialized and includes Views support. The feature is available in the current release version.

Comment: +1 - Sounds like the proper solution. Thanks for pointing this out here.

Comment: Thanks John! Will check the new version out as well

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Views modify query](http://drupal.org/project/views_modify_query) module.